# Adjust background color for pdf in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview

I'm reading a lot of pdf's in Preview's full screen mode. Usually this means I'm looking at a fully white screen with black characters. I'm getting mad after an hour of reading..

Is there a way of adjusting the colours/contrast in Preview temporarily? For example in TexShop the white background is automatically changed to a grey-value. For me it's probably fine if I'd able to change the white background to grey, but maybe its possible to even change it to another color like the nightmode on iOs?

Is this possible with Preview out-of-the-box? Can it be changed temporarily/only on viewing? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there the dark mode (inverted colors) in the 'Preview' Application for PDF reading?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317845/is-there-the-dark-mode-inverted-colors-in-the-preview-application-for-pdf-re)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to turn on the night shift function and to push it to a warmer color map: `System Preferences > Displays > Night Shift`.
[image: Night shift]

This will protect your retina and your brain.

It might be worth trying the `Invert colors` mode:
`System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Invert colors`.
[image: Invert colors]

Comment: Using light theme in General settings can improve the inverted experience further

Comment: Thank you. I don't have this function in my production environnment (High Sierra).

Answer (score 1):

[Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) is an alternative PDF reader, which provides many advantages over Preview, including a Preference setting for the background colour.

(Not affiliated: just a happy user.)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84999/change-background-colour-for-pdf-when-viewing?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Preview doesn't have that option but you can use [F.Lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) to make screen itself warm (yellowish) and thus softer on eyes.

[Change background colour for PDF when Viewing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84999/change-background-colour-for-pdf-when-viewing)