# What is a program to display PDF's in a dark theme friendly fashion on MacOS?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf, dark-mode

I am trying to read all my PDF's in dark theme, to preserve my vision since I work at a computer all day.

Adobe Acrobat reader offers this feature, in that you can go into accessibility and change the background color and also the color of text. This would work great, except that on my machine, an M1 Mac Air, it constantly crashes, refuses to open, or just sits there consuming 100%+ CPU resources.

Ideally I would like another program which at the least, will flip black and white text, and at best, would actually make the text and background a user-configurable color, like black and green.

Most importantly, it won't crash constantly and hopefully be more lightweight than Adobe.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Edit: this question may be a duplicate, check other answers here
[Change background colour for PDF when Viewing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84999/change-background-colour-for-pdf-when-viewing)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:
I’ve switched to the Highlights app since it has a fullscreen reading mode that I like: https://highlightsapp.net**

I like the Negative app: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/negative/id1378123825?mt=12

or NightPDF:
https://github.com/librepgp/NightPDF - this link is dead

There is a NightPDF https://github.com/Lunarequest/NightPDF but I(mmmmmm) don't know if it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/), you can choose the background color:

[image]

Comment: So you change black text on white background to black text on black background?

Answer (score -1):

I would try Apple’s preview app. It works for all my needs except when we have massively complicated layered PDF at work with all sorts of prepress data like ink levels embedded in the “PDF”

Comment: How do I make a PDF display in dark theme on Preview?

Comment: Invert colors in the Accessibility pane is the hammer method I find when the text is too white for me.