# Make PDF dark-mode friendly in Adobe DC Acrobat Reader or alternative

Tags: pdf, python, color, dark-mode

I was looking for a way to read a PDF in "dark mode". Found this answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84999/change-background-colour-for-pdf-when-viewing) However I was curios if there's a way to make Adobe Acrobat Reader more dark-mode friendly or if there exists an alternative to it; because currently, Python line codes ("line art" is how they are called in Adobe Acrobat Reader, if I am not mistaken) are indecipherable sometimes. For instance, in the photo you can see that the blue text below the "Load the data" comment below is hard to be read. (see photo) [image]

Comment: So you're looking at PDFs of code, and want to change the colour of the background and text? Scripts would be more useful as raw text, and you could then use any number of text editors with custom syntax colouring.

Comment: @benwiggy they are not PDFs of code. It's a book with code snippets.